# Accessing Blender docs in wake of DDOS attack?

Tags: documentation

Please say if there's a different tech forum that's a better place for this question.

The Blender website is [back online after the DDOS attack](https://mstdn.social/@fsiddi/111449488852727485) of the past few days. But I'm still not able to access [docs.Blender.org](https://docs.Blender.org), getting this error from Firefox:

```
Secure Connection Failed
Error code: SSL_ERROR_NO_CYPHER_OVERLAP
```

[Checking it at SSL Labs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=docs.blender.org), I get six results that all say, "Failed to communicate with the secure server".

Two questions:

- Is there a way to get the status of the docs site and an idea of when it will be available again?
- Is there a mirror of the docs site where the current docs can be accessed or where the docs zip files can be downloaded? [Archive.org has the home page of the 4.0 manual](https://web.archive.org/web/20231120205935/https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/), but the links on it go to pages for previous versions and attempts to download the zips from there fail after about 15 or 20 Mb.

My lesson from this is to download those docs to my computer for future reference. But is there anything I can do to access the docs before the docs site comes back online?

Comment: The only thing I know is what is written in the "Latest News" on the Blender site: _"Several websites are still unavailable (code, developer, docs, devtalk, download, wiki, etc.) – and we keep working to bring them back."_ Which sounds to me as if there is no other mirror for those docs (or at least none I would trust right now) and they don't know how long it will take. But is there something special you need to know right now (and couldn't ask here) that cannot wait until the site is up again? I rarely use the docs, mostly just to confirm something for users in answers I'm posting here.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann - Thank you. That referral to the news item is helpful. For reference: https://www.blender.org/news/cyberattack-november-2023/